SelectPDF landscape not using full width for footer
When the page orientation is set to landscape, I'm struggling to get SelectPDF to use the full width of the page for the PdfHtmlSection.
When the orientation is portrait, the footer fills fine:

When it's landscape, the footer falls, like, 20px short on the right:

The page's actual content fills the width correctly regardless of the orientation. It's just the footer that doesn't. (The PDF does not use a header.)
My code is...
converter.Options.DisplayFooter = true;
converter.Footer.Height = 80;
FooterTemplate footer = trivialModelData;
var footerHtml = new ViewToStringQuery<FooterTemplate>("Footer.cshtml", footer);
var footerSection = new PdfHtmlSection(footerHtml, applicationURL);
converter.Footer.Add(footerSection);

I tried using the override to PdfHtmlSection() that specifies a width and setting it to an obscene number like 5000. It didn't change the output.
Footer.cshtml to match the snapshots is...
@model KrystalBall.PDF.API.Models.Template.FooterTemplate
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;500;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Roboto, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
            color: #333;
            font-size: 11pt;
            height: 40pt;
                        background-color: blue;
        }

        .footer {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: flex-start;
                        width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="footer">
    </div>
</body>
</html>

Has anyone run into this before?
